# Reverse plus Even and Odd of an array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am a newbie to programming. I am trying to create a program that would display an array in reverse. Plus also find the even and odd numbers of an array,sum the count and also display the even and odd numbers. The code works but the problem is that it also reverses the even and odd arrays and it shows this weird zero in those arrays. What am I doing wrong?
Please also provide explanation. Thanks!

```
 import java.util.Arrays;
 public class ArrayTest {

   public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};
    for ( int i=0; i<array.length/2; i++ )
    {
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[array.length-(1+i)];
        array[array.length-(1+i)] = temp;
    }
    System.out.println("Array after reverse: \n" + Arrays.toString(array));

     int even=0;
     int odd=0;
     int[] Even = new int[13];
     int[] Odd = new int[13];
    for ( int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            Even[i] = array[i];
            even++;
        }
        else
        {
            Odd[i] = array[i];
            odd++;
        }

    }
  System.out.println("Even: "+even+" ");
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Even));
  System.out.println("Odd:  "+odd+" ");
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Odd));

   }
}
```

The output is:

Array after reverse:

[13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

Even: 6

[0, 12, 0, 10, 0, 8, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0]

Odd:  7

[13, 0, 11, 0, 9, 0, 7, 0, 5, 0, 3, 0, 1]

Comment: And what output are you expecting exactly?

Comment: Array after reverse:


[13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]


Even: 6

[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]



Odd: 7


[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]

Comment: I would suggest you figure out the steps without using Java first, then translate it into code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your logic

```
 int[] Even = new int[(array.length/2)+1];
 int[] Odd = new int[(array.length/2)+1];
for ( int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
    if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        Even[even] = array[i];
        even++;
    }
    else
    {
        Odd[odd] = array[i];
        odd++;
    }

}
```

As per you code, you are initializing array of size `13` for odd and even, which is not correct.

```
 int[] Even = new int[13];
 int[] Odd = new int[13];
```

So, by default, `Even` and `Odd` array will be initialized by `0` value. Then, you are setting value as per main array, which a size of `13` on alternate basis (even/odd).

**==Updated==**

Since, you don't want `Even` and `Odd` array in reverse order. Then, you can move the code up.

**[>>Demo<<](https://ideone.com/ZQPeDQ)**

Comment: Thanks for correcting me :) But i still don't get it why it is displaying Even and Odd arrays in reverse?

Comment: Because, you are assigning `even` and `odd` variable using `array` variable, which is in reverse order

Comment: How can I correct this. Can you please explain a little more. thanks!

Comment: I have already corrected the code and posted in my answer. And also, I have provided a demo link as well. Did you checked it ?

Comment: Do you still have doubt ?

Comment: Hey, I just mentioned, you are using  main `array` variable, which is in reverse order. That's the reason you are getting `even` and `odd` as in reverse order as well. I'm not getting why it is so hard to understand

Comment: No I get your point. But I am confused whether i should declare another array variable or can I do something in the existing code. Please forgive me. I am newbie ;( I am learning by myself. It would be more helpful if you can show me in a code.

Comment: I have updated the code and used `ArrayList` instead. Please check the `Demo` link. Also, don't forget to accept and upvote.

Comment: Now I get it all. Thanks for your kind help:)

Answer (score 0):

1. You select even and odd numbers from reversed array.
2. You use wrong index for even and odd arrays.
3. If you don't want to see zeros in output, use print in for statement. Another solution - firstly count odd and even numbers and create arrays with exact size.

   ```
   import java.util.Arrays;
   public class ArrayTest {

       public static void main(String[] args) 
       {      
           int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};

           int even=0;
           int odd=0;
           int[] Even = new int[13];
           int[] Odd = new int[13];

          for ( int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
          {
              if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
              {
                  Even[even++] = array[i];
              }
              else
              {
                  Odd[odd++] = array[i];
              }

          }
           for ( int i=0; i<array.length/2; i++ )
           {
               int temp = array[i];
               array[i] = array[array.length-(1+i)];
               array[array.length-(1+i)] = temp;
           }
           System.out.println("Array after reverse: \n" + Arrays.toString(array));


         System.out.println("Even: "+even+" ");
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Even));
         System.out.println("Odd:  "+odd+" ");
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Odd));

      }
   }
   ```

Comment: Nicely Explained. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You faced 2 problems (I guess so)

1. *The odd and even arrays are also in reverse order*

   **Reason**: The first For loop reverses the 'array' and stores the results in array itself. So, the next time when you try working with 'array' to find odd/even numbers, you are actually working with the reversed array.

   **Solution**: You can assign the original array to a backup array and use that backup array to find odd and even nos.
2. *Unnecessary zeros*:

   **Reason**: In your second for loop you used odd[i]=array[i] which seems to be a logical error in your code. Consider the case:

   value of i       :     0 1 2 3 4 5 ... 12

   value of array[i]:     1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 13

   value of odd[i]  :     1 0 3 0 5 0 ... 13

   value of even[i] :     0 2 0 4 0 6 ... 0

This means, the control inside for loop is made to flow either to if{} block or the else{} block and not the both. So, when if(condition) is satisfied, then even[i] array will be updated. But meanwhile what happens to the odd[i] array? It retains the inital value '0'. That's it!

I hope the following code helps you:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class A
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
   int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};
   int[] arr2 = new int[array.length];   // backup array
   arr2=Arrays.copyOfRange(array,0,array.length);
   for ( int i=0; i<arr2.length/2; i++ )
   {
    int temp = arr2[i];
    arr2[i] = arr2[arr2.length-(1+i)];
    arr2[arr2.length-(1+i)] = temp;
   }
   System.out.println("Array after reverse: \n" + Arrays.toString(arr2));
   int even=0;
   int odd=0;
   int[] Even = new int[13];
   int[] Odd = new int[13];
   for ( int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
   {
    if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        Even[even] = array[i];
        even++;
    }
    else
    {
        Odd[odd] = array[i];
        odd++;
    }
  }
  Even=Arrays.copyOfRange(Even,0,even);
  Odd=Arrays.copyOfRange(Odd,0,odd);
  System.out.println("Even: "+even+" ");
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Even));
  System.out.println("Odd:  "+odd+" ");
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Odd));
 }
}
```

***Note:***  I have used *Arrays.copyOfRange(array,start,end)* function to copy a certain part of the array from start to end-1 position.

**Output:**

Array after reverse:

[13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

Even: 6

[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]

Odd:  7

[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]

Hope this helps :)

--Mathan Madhav

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what i needed:)

Comment: Its interesting to note that assigning int backup_array[]=original_array is a bad programming approach because once if 'original_array' is changed, the backup_array also changes as it is an instance of original_array. Its always good to copy arrays rather than simply assigning it to a temporary array!

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing. By copying array you mean to declare another array of the same elements?

Comment: Yes.. Its simply copying the entire array to a backup array. This process do not create any instance of the original array copied. So even original array is modified, backup array remains the same!

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Got it now :)

Comment: No mention! Kindly upvote the answer if you find useful. Happy Java!  :)